# WillPopScope does not work from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, textfield, back-button-control

I have multiple widgets in my flutter app. If I click at another widget, onWillPopScope method which is defined at the top of `Widget build(BuildContext context)` does not working. Could you give me advice how to fix it? Thanks

See below code:

```
 ExpansionTile(
                                  initiallyExpanded: false,
                                  title:
                                  Text('Solution', style: basicAlertBlack),
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      color: Colors.amber.shade50,
                                      height:
                                      MediaQuery
                                          .of(context)
                                          .size
                                          .height /
                                          7,
                                      child: _solutionTextField(),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
```

Code of second widget:

```
 Widget _solutionTextField() {
 return TextField(

    focusNode: myFocusNode,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    maxLines: null,
    style: solution,
    controller: solutionController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Enter a solution'));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context, please?

As [documentations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) says:

## WillPopScope class

Registers a callback to veto attempts by the user to dismiss the enclosing ModalRoute.

It means that it will be called on `pop` actions. It could be called from android navigation by clicking the return arrow or iOS by swiping from edge left side to right. And every other `pop` method that you call via `Navigator`. So it doesn't have a connection with clicking at Widget.